# AJAX and jQuery validate issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, contacts

So I got stuck in this dead end. I have AJAX script and jQuery Validation plug-in. With this script, when my page loads empty contact form automatically submits on itself. If I move or add `$('#submit').click(function () {` over AJAX script part, right below `$(document).ready(function() {` then on submit it ignores my validation form.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
<script>
    var captcha_a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var captcha_b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var captcha_c = captcha_a + captcha_b;

    function generate_captcha(id){
        var id = (id) ? id : 'lcaptcha';
        $("#"+id).html(captcha_a + " + " + captcha_b + " = ");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submit').click(function () {

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("math",
                function(value, element, params) { return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1]; },
                jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}")
            );

            $("#commentform").validate({
                rules: {
                    captcha: {
                        math: [captcha_a, captcha_b]
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    })
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var name = $('input[name=name]');
        var phone = $('input[name=phone]');
        var email = $('input[name=email]');
        var reason = $('select[name=reason]');
        var info = $('textarea[name=info]');

        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&email=' + email.val() +'&reason=' + reason.val() + '&info='  + encodeURIComponent(info.val());

        $('.loading').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxformtoemail.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: data, 
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {  
                if (html==1) {
                    $('.form').fadeOut('slow'); 
                    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
                } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
            }
         });
         return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I indented & formatted your code for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ajax` is running on page load because nothing is stopping it.  You need to put the `ajax` code inside an event handler so it's only called if/when your form passes validation.

The following is an example of the proper implementation of the Validation Plugin.  And you do not need to put the `validate()` inside a click handler.  The Validation plugin has a bunch of its own handlers built in including a `submitHandler` that fires when the form passes validation.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("math",
        function(value, element, params) { return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1]; },
        jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}")
    );

    $('form').validate({
        rules {
            // your rules
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                // your ajax parameters
            });         
            return false;
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

[Validation Plugin Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Some side issues...

1. Your code would be much easier to read & troubleshoot if you used proper indentation and standard formatting.
2. There is not need to use duplicate `document.ready` functions.  Everything can be inside one.
3. Like in #2, you do not need separate sets of `<script></script>` tags to contain your code.  Everything can be enclosed once.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sparky. Iv used "stackoverflow" for references before, but this is my very first time actually asking for help. So, Ill get better with proper indentation. Thank you for your advise, I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: OoMuGaaaash!!! IT'S ALIIVE!!!! I spent the whole weekends trying figure this out. Brother, what is your Paypal email account, let me buy you a beer. Should of ask you last Friday, so I could spend some time with my gf instead. Thank you Sparky, thank you 'submitHandler: function(form)'

Comment: @user1234729, I'm glad you figured it out.  I suggest you dig into the live Validation examples posted in the plugin's documentation... they can be more useful than the official docs which are somewhat difficult to navigate.