# Multipart jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate, validation

I'm trying to validate different parts of a form separately. Unfortunately, the form is generated by a CMS, so I'm limited in my manipulation.

I've tried creating an array of `validate` objects, using the current form section as an index. Ie:

```
  //initialize validation
  validators = [
    $('#donation_amount').validate({ rules:{ amount: { required: true } } }),
    $('#personal_information').validate({ rules:{ Street: { required: true } } })
   ];
```

and shifting through the sections like so:

```
  $('#btn-next').click(function() {
    //if validation is true, show next page
    if (validators[curOrder].valid()) {
      var old = $('.active');
      var oldOrder = old.attr('data-order');
      var newOrder = parseInt(oldOrder) + 1;
      old.removeClass('active');
      $("[data-order='" + newOrder + "']").addClass('active');
      curOrder = newOrder;
    }else{
      console.log("invalid");
   }
});
```

The validation, however, is always returning `true`.

Here's the page in question: https://salsa3.salsalabs.com/o/50388/p/salsa/donation/common/public/?donate_page_KEY=8461

Comment: You should **not** place `.validate()` _inside_ a `click` handler.  It's meant to initialize the form and should be inside the `document.ready` instead.  When you need to test the form inside events, use `.valid()` which will return a true/false.  Otherwise, there are events already built into `.validate()` that you can use.  See:  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9460920/594235), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11068130/594235), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10825498/594235).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But how do I change the validation rules on command? That seems like where I'd what to re-initialize the form on each section shift.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and I don't fully understand how you want to do this.  What I've done in the past is break up the multi-part form into multiple forms.  Initialize `validate()` on all forms _once_, and use `.valid()` to test the form upon clicking the `next` button.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. So, on each step, I only want to validate the showing fields. Thus, if I have one comprehensive block of rules, it'll return an invalid result even if the user hasn't had to access those fields yet, right?

Comment: Then my previous comment stands.  Each part is its own `form` that you can validate separately.  Otherwise, you are dealing with something that's very unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. However, now it's returning `true` all the time. I've updated the example code with the new stuff. Is it more inline with your suggestion now?

Comment: It seems to be.  Can I assume the initialization is inside a `document.ready`?  And if each section is now contained within its own `form`, then why do you need to mess around with the `.active` classes and such?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17151/discussion-between-asherlc-and-sparky672)

Comment: I have to log off now... late for my appointment.  Hopefully somebody else can help.  Otherwise, I can continue later.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even using .validate plugin when you are writing a little javascript yourself. On click, just check the value of the inputs (like $('#myInput').val().trim() == "") and show/hide the respective error div against each input.

Further, for multipart validation, validate only the required fields and continue what is supposed to.

```
$('#btn-next').click(function() {
var amountValid = $('#donation_amount').val().trim() == '' ? false : true;
var infoValid = $('#personal_information').val().trim() == '' ? false : true;

if (amountValid && infoValid) {
  var old = $('.active');
  var oldOrder = old.attr('data-order');
  var newOrder = parseInt(oldOrder) + 1;
  old.removeClass('active');
  $("[data-order='" + newOrder + "']").addClass('active');
      curOrder = newOrder;
    }else{
      console.log("invalid");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm going to be checking the validity of email addresses, number formats, etc. It's also going to need to add invalid labels and classes. That all seems like I'd be reinventing the wheel, and in some pretty cumbersome ways, if I tossed out the validation plugin.