# JQuery Validation Plugin EqualTo

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

So here's a working demo of my problem: [bin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/37548/edit). First click on the button for the content to be viewable. Next, navigate to the second tab, passwords. Here is where the problem lies. The EqualTo call in the validation plugin is not returning properly. Even when `New Password` and `Verify Password` are correct, equalTo returns false. I don't understand why and was hoping someone could figure it out.

Notes:
* I put the plugin initialization inside the if statement which is inside the click callback because the slider displays very oddly when outside of all that. It has something to do with the hide event screwing up positioning. So i simply put it inside the callback and made sure it only initializes once.

Comment: this selector in `equalTo` is pointless `.coda-slider-wrapper .coda-nav .current #new_password`  An ID must be unique, just use the ID for the selector. Is faster and less error prone to coding mistake

Comment: @charlietfl what exactly do you mean, are you saying to just do `#new_password` because if so, then i've already tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: yes... is much simpler and more efficient. Doesn't mean it resolves issue. I don't really undertsand the demo yet...not clear what links are about and can't see form fields

Comment: @charlietfl the demo just shows you that no matter what, the validation always returns false for the comparison between the `New Password` field and the `Verify Password` field. I've found that jquery just is unable to find the `New Password` field. Here's an updated [demo](http://jsbin.com/welcome/37563/edit). Here if you type something in inside the `New Password` field and hit submit, it should alert you with the value of the box. But it returns a blank or `undefined` for now since it can't find it.

Comment: want help..scale this down to simplest format, no slider or extra methods. Most times the tabs code fails and I can't see form. Also not sure what a valid password format is. Frustrating

Comment: @charlietfl there's no problem in the simplest form, the problem only arises when you put inside the slider. So it doesn't really help to scale it down. Also valid password method is right above the click callback. Here's the regex: `/^(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/.test(value)`

Comment: OK  is slider manipulatng the form html then after validate is called?

Comment: @charlietfl i have no idea. I found a solution though, i just have a hidden field that copies the value of the `new_password` field. I don't really like solutions like that but it's the best I got right now

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question itself.  Please do not reply on an external link to stay alive in order for this question to be useful to others in the future.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is some interaction between codaSlider and jQuery Validate.  If you take out the codaSlider script and code, your validation script works (if you change the equalTo to `equalTo: '#new_password'`).

Here's your bin edited to work without codaSlider:  http://jsbin.com/welcome/37927/edit

**EDIT**: I looked over the source code for codaSlider, and somewhere deep in it's event handling, it deals poorly with clicks that happen within the slider elements.  I think it's overriding how jQuery Validate deals with submit clicks, among possibly other things.  If you add the option `continuous:false` to your codaSlider, I think that will fix this interaction without breaking codaSlider for the use you have.  Here's that version in action: http://jsbin.com/welcome/37989/edit

Comment: so you took coda slider out? I fully understand that validation plugin works under normal conditions, I use it for my entire website. The question was posted to ask how to make it work under specific conditions such as implemented inside of coda. This answer was completely unhelpful

Comment: Fair enough - I admit I didn't read your question very far past the link :)  I'll take another look!

Comment: The root problem is not a conflict with codaSlider, but a conflict between two different `submit` handlers... the one built into `validate()` and the additional one added by the OP.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I disagree that the custom submit handler is causing any problems.  Sure, OP should use `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler` in Validate to deal with the form, but it really doesn't change the outcome wrt validate working correctly in this case.

Comment: Looking at it again, he initializes the `validate()` plugin from within his `submit()` handler.  This is very wrong.  `validate()` needs to be initialized once when the page loads, not every time the button is clicked.  If the validation plugin is not initialized when the page loads, no validation will occur on first click.

Comment: @Sparky672 - He did something crazy with the 2nd `submit` handler, but even removing that AND only initializing `validate` once doesn't fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

<s>The root</s> (A problem) is that you're adding an independent `submit` handler function when the `validate()` plugin already includes its own `submitHandler:` function.  **edit:**  The root problem is that the `validate()` plugin is not even initialized until you hit `submit`.

Initialize `validate()` within the `document.ready` and let the `validate()` plugin handle the `submit` event as it was intended to do...

```
$("#change_Pass").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    errorClass: "password_messages",
    debug: true, // remove this for production code
    rules: {
        change_password: {
            required: true
        },
        new_password: {
            required: true,
            passw: true
        },
        verify_password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: ".coda-slider-wrapper .coda-nav .current #new_password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        change_password: {
            required: "Please enter your current password"
        },
        new_password: {
            required: "Please enter a new password"
        },
        verify_password: {
            required: "Please verify your new password",
            equalTo: "Your passwords did not match"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert($('#new_password').val());
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            alert("Success");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

jsFiddle Demo with extraneous code stripped:

http://jsfiddle.net/9SYr5/3/

---

**EDIT:**

Additionally, the `validate()` plugin needs to be initialized **once** when the page loads, not every single time the submit button is clicked.

Improperly initializing the plugin seems to be a very popular thing to do; see these SO links for all the various issues caused by this improper practice.  All of these SO questions have one thing in common, `validate()` is improperly initialized by placing it within a `submit()` or `click()` handler.

1)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936025/594235  (multiple submit clicks required)

> Since you enclosed `.validate()` within `.submit()`, the Validation
>   function does not even load until you hit submit. Since it's not
>   already loaded when you hit submit, no validation will occur. Then
>   when you hit submit the second time, the function is now loaded so it
>   appears to work normally.
>
> When you enclose `.validate()` within `document.ready`, the Validation
>   plugin loads immediately as the DOM is finished loaded. Therefore,
>   it's ready and waiting for you to interact with your form and it
>   behaves correctly on the first submit.

More...

2)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068130/594235 (won't validate when inside click handler)

3)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10825498/594235 (does not work on second submit)

4)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609871/594235 (validation will not run a second time)

5)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10987058/594235 (initialize new form on submit won't work)

6)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460920/594235 (validation is ignored)

Comment: You've misread the question (same as I did!) - the interaction between codaSlider and validate is 100% the problem.  OP knows that they work separately and even says that in the quesiton.

Comment: @Ryley, Maybe so, but what he's trying to do and the way it's being done seems very convoluted and verbose, respectively.

Comment: @Ryley, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9936025/594235) and read the part at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're finding this - he only is creating the validation when the form is displayed (admittedly, it is recreated if you were to reclick the original button).  There's no reason not to do it the way you're describing, BUT that still doesn't fix the problem he's having.

Comment: @Ryley, yeah, the whole thing is still very oddly implemented.